# What is the size of the data that I can maintain in SQLite in a desktop application?

Tags: sqlite

If have you use SQLite to develop a Desktop application, will there be any limitation to the size of data that I can store into it ?
Will there be any performance issues ? 
As I read somewhere that browers use it to store settings only..and nothing much..
Thanks...

Comment: see [Limits In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Comment: I use SQLite routinely for 400MB databases with excellent performance and have read of others using it for much larger datasets than that. Size is not so much its limitation as its concurrent-writers model. What browsers do or don't do with SQLite is not an indication of its capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Implementation Limits For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html):

> The largest possible setting for SQLITE_MAX_PAGE_COUNT is 2147483646. When used with the maximum page size of 65536, this gives a maximum SQLite database size of about 14 terabytes.

The max file size could be smaller depending on your filesystem. As for performance, that depends more on your schema, queries, indices, type of data being stored, etc.